# Problem with getting data from a SQL table with foreign keys in a WCF project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wcf, ado.net, wcf-data-services, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a problem with my WCF project in Visual Studio. I have connected a SQL database with ADO.NET Entity Data Model to the project.

So far everything works. For example when I want to get data from a view in my database there is no problem or error. For that I use the following code:

```
public interface IWCF
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<view_table1> GettingData();
}

public class Service_WCF : IWCF
{
    public Database_Entity db = new Database_Entity();
   
    public List<view_table1> GettingData();
    {
        return db.view_table1.ToList();
    }
}
```

When I debug the `WCF_Service.svc` and call the `GettingData()` method in the WCF test client, I get the data from the view. So that works with no problem and all other `[OperationContracts]` too.

But when I want to load data from a normal table and not a view I get an error every time. The table I want to load data from in the test client has a connection to two other tables in the SQL database. The connections are all loaded by the model when creating it so I thing they should be OK.

The error I am getting in the WCF test client is:

> Fehler beim Empfangen der HTTP-Antwort für http://localhost:65373/WCF_Service.svc. Die Ursache kann sein, dass die Dienstendpunktbindung kein HTTP-Protokoll verwendet. Eine andere mögliche Ursache ist, dass der HTTP-Anforderungskontext vom Server abgebrochen wird (vermutlich auf das Herunterfahren des Diensts zurückzuführen). Weitere Informationen finden Sie in den Serverprotokollen.
>
> Server stack trace:
>
> bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
> bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
> bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
> bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
> bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
> bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
> bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>
> bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
> bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
> bei IWCF.GettingData()
> bei WCFClient.GettingData()
>
> Inner Exception:
>
> Die zugrunde liegende Verbindung wurde geschlossen: Unbekannter Fehler beim Empfangen..
>
> bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> Inner Exception:
>
> Von der Übertragungsverbindung können keine Daten gelesen werden: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen.
> bei System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>
> bei System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> bei System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
>
> Inner Exception:
> Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen
>
> bei System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
> bei System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

However the strange thing is when I debug the WCF and set a break point in the code and use a var like this:

```
public List<table1> GettingDataFromTableNotView();
{
    var b = db.table1.ToList();
    return b;
}
```

Then the var b has the value that is in the "table1" and I can view it in the code while debugging. But when I click the button that the program should go on after the breakpoint, I get the error again. So the WCF can get the data but it can't return it and that is strange to me.

I also tried things like:

```
var b = db.table1.Include("table2").Include("table3").ToList();
return b;
```

that did not work.

I also tried in the `Model.Context.cs` to turn on `LazyLoadingEnabled = true`.

Comment: Hello, are you testing locally? At the same time, I can't reproduce the problem with your code. Can you provide more code? Thanks!